# Change order of files in solution explorer

Tags: visual-studio, project, projects-and-solutions, projects

In Visual Studio, how do you change the order of your source files?

By default, it seems that they go in alphabetical order but I want to put them in a more logical order.

Comment: Those of us coming to C# from F# would like to have this feature.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't change the order that the Solution Explorer displays your files. If you need a more logical grouping, consider using folders and namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

The usual solution would be to prefix the filenames with numbers. This is at least useful for folders, e.g. `00_comes_first`, `01_externals`, `01_tools`, `99_last_of_the_important_folders` would appear near the top before any files starting with letters.

Unfortunately, Microsoft broke this in recent releases of Visual Studio (17.6 and up) and now the numbered directories appear last unlike in every other piece of software (including the git changes view in VS).  Feel free to upvote the corresponding bug report https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Ordering-in-Solution-Explorer-changed-n/10371646