# How to change order of files in Solution Explorer in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

For the current project I'm working on there is this convention where Readme documents are put in folders explaining their responsibility and giving info about it. Thus, it would be benefitial if somehow those readme files could stay as the first file in each folder. Instead, Visual Studio orders them by alphabetically.

Is it possible to change order of files in Solution Explorer in Visual Studio?

EDIT: Always at the bottom also works.

Comment: "You can't change the order" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826975/change-order-of-files-in-solution-explorer

Comment: Would using '_readme' help? Does your convention allow that?

Answer (score 0):

> I don't think you can.But you can **sort** by various things in
>   **class view**.

[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2]