# Visual Studio 2017 sort solution explorer by file type and alphabeticlly

Tags: visual-studio-2017, file-type, solution-explorer

can someone tell me how to sort the vs 2017 solution explorer by both type and alphabetically?

basically I want this config file to be at the bottom of the project..

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change order of files in solution explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826975/change-order-of-files-in-solution-explorer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't sort the files within Visual Studio, they will always be alphabetical.

Best you can do is group files using folders.